# Can i refresh full sandbox except Case object

Tags: apex

Can i refresh my full sandbox except case.
As i dont want to refresh my case when iam trying to refresh full sandbox.

Comment: Do you mean data or metadata ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no controls in the sandbox refresh to allow some items to be updated and others skipped. The only ways I know to accomplish this are to use a change set or use Eclipse to copy the case object to another sandbox temporarily while the full sandbox is refreshed.

If you use a change set to copy the case object, remember that you also need to copy any changed fields, layouts etc. to the new sandbox as well.  After you've refreshed the sandbox, you can copy all the elements back.

If you use Eclipse, you won't have to specify all the individual fields etc belonging to the case.